# Utilizing IHeaderHandler with wcf

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, soap

I have a rather outdated assembly that I'm using to communicate via SOAP with software my company writes. As it stands right now, getting the assembly updated is not an option, so please don't suggest it.

In previous iterations the normal method of communication was done utilizing the MS Soap Toolkit 3.0 (MSSOAPLIB30). You would call the login() method of the assembly and it would return an instance derived from IHeaderHandler that you would then assign to the instance of the soap client. [Please refer here for more information on how this worked.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms862164.aspx)

Well, I would like to use a more updated approach for communication with this web service. Thus far I have been able to successfully reference the web service with wcf, however I'm running into issues figuring out how to bridge the IHeaderHandler instance to something that the wcf proxy can comprehend. In other words, I'm trying to bridge two generations of technologies together. I've verified that using the method mentioned in the link above does actually work. Now it's just a matter of figuring out how to make this instance of IHeaderHandler useful.

Here is some example code for the old approach:

```
string strBasicWsdlUrl = "http://" + _strDeviceName + "/MetasysIII/WS/TimeManagement/TimeService.asmx";
object[] Parameters1 = new object[] { strBasicWsdlUrl, "", "", "" };
bool[] Parameters2 = new bool[] { true, true, true, true };

TSClient = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MSSOAP.SoapClient30"));
NewLateBinding.LateGet(TSClient, null, "MSSoapInit", Parameters1, null, null, Parameters2);

Parameters1 = new object[] { NewLateBinding.LateGet(JCISecurity, null, "HeaderHandler", new object[0], null, null, null) };
NewLateBinding.LateSet(TSClient, null, "HeaderHandler", Parameters1, null, null);
```

As you can see, a new instance of the soap client is initialized with the wsdl file and then the HeaderHandler attribute from the JCISecurity instance (which is the aforementioned assembly I'm using to authenticate with the software) which is derived from IHeaderHandler is passed to the HeaderHandler of the soap client. This process then ensures that all future requests from the soap client have this header attached.

It's also important to note that the proxy class generated from WCF for my web service has two interesting parameters attached to all web methods: EncryptedCertificate and LoginResult. I'm assuming these values will exist in the IHeaderHandler instance as the original documentation of the service does not reference these two parameters. However, I cannot verify this is the case because I've yet to be able to figure out how to access the content embedded in the IHeaderHandler instance.

As it stands, I see two possible solutions at this point: Figure out a way to make the WCF proxy class directly use the IHeaderHandler instance being generated with the assembly or figure out a way to extract the necessary information from the IHeaderHandler instance and use Message Inspectors to manually attach the details to the headers.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF is very extensible. One of those extension points is [Message Inspectors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx):

> A message inspector is an extensibility object that can be used in the service model's client runtime and dispatch runtime programmatically or through configuration and that can inspect and alter messages after they are received or before they are sent.

See also [WCF Extensibility Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd699779.aspx) and [Extending WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733848.aspx).

Comment: Thank you John. My primary problem is accessing the data embedded in the IHeaderHandler instance. I've been trying for the past couple of hours to find a way to get inside of it and see what's actually being done. If I could get a firm grasp on it's role and what exactly it's attaching to the header I might be able to emulate it with a Message Inspector. Please see the bottom of my updated post for more details.

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that it's simply not possible to migrate the IHeaderHandler instance to something wcf can understand. I'm quite disappointed in Microsoft, I would of hoped they would have handled migration a tad bit better. Then again, the fact that this question is now the top of my Google search results is enough evidence that what I'm attempting to do is rather rare.

Comment: You're jumping several generations of technology. It's unlikely that a migration would already exist across so many generations. Was there even a migration between the SOAP Toolkit and WSE 1.0 or .NET 1.0? I don't think so.

Comment: I'd figured at some point during the transition they would of provided some bridges. I can't even seem to get an implementation of IStream to try and read the header that the soap client is producing.

Comment: I would take this as an opportunity to ask yourself: how many other ancient technologies are you using that you need to update before everyone but you and I forgets that they ever existed? What percent of the [so] community do you think has ever even _heard_ of `IStream`? What percentage have ever used the SOAP Toolkit? You could easily get to the point where only a few hundred people in the entire world can help you with issues like this.

Comment: I understand, thanks for your patience on the matter John. I suppose I'm just the type that will try to exhaust every last possible solution to get something to work. I come from an industry where I sometimes service equipment that was made back in the late 80's to early 90's and "you just need to upgrade it" is not a sufficient answer for the customer. So, as you can imagine, I was a little stubborn regarding this issue. Anyways, thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Sometimes, "upgrade it" means, "upgrade your horse - buy a car, or you'll begin to have trouble finding livery stables on your route, and they may not even let you ride the horse where you used to ride, and if you buy a car, you'll get places much faster, and you'll be able to go places you never would have gone to before because it used to be too slow, and ..."